# Checkbox buttontint color in API level 16

Tags: android

I want to change **checkbox** button color since for **jellybeans** and below version the default color is **black** and I want **white** color

I tried this : `android:buttonTint` **but it says it will be supported for API 21 and higher**.

Then I tried this :

```
<style name="WhiteCheck" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
 <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
</style>

<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:textColor="@color/off_white"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteCheck"
        />
```

**But colorAccent is supported by the AppCompat library. android:colorAccent would be supported by API 21.**

Is it not possible if yes, then how?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:colorAccent` atribute

```
<style name="WhiteCheck" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

See also [material design theme reference](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette)

Comment: Look at my code I dont want to vote you down....look what I tried at first please then post an answer

Comment: `android:colorAccent` and `colorAccent` - is it same things?

Comment: can we even achieve material design pre 21 versions?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve material design api level<=16  first tell me this

Comment: I use material design at API 16 level with support library

Comment: which library give me the link please? and also tell me how to change this button tint color too

Comment: [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html)

Comment: I guess I am already using one see this if its the same thing 
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.+'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132772/discussion-between-sergey-and-samh67).

Comment: Sergey, `android:colorAccent` changes the color on >=21 devices only, `colorAccent` is an attribute from the support library allowing backporting of the color to pre 21 devices.

Answer (score 0):

For **API<21**

If you are intersted to change the background color of the checkbox (button) use

```
mcheckbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.someotherbackground);
```

where someotherbackground is an image in the drawable folder to which background you want your checkbox to be changed

try as below

```
 mcheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {
           // mcheckbox.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  //Use if you want to change Color
            System.out.println("checked" + isChecked);
            mcheckbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.imageWhenActive);
                System.out.println("app constant is set as "+isChecked);
        }
        else
        {
        // mcheckbox.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);  //Use if you want to change Color
            mcheckbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.imageWheninactive);
            System.out.println("app constant is set as "+isChecked);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: I am not using background image let me reassure you first

Comment: You can use Colour in your drawable . or you can use commented line. Just give a try. @SamH67